# How to add an Auto Responses for the Events created?

Tags: events

I have several events created using ExpressionEngine on my website. Currently when someone registers for a training or workshop, I manually respond via email with a welcome letter and a pdf attachment of a reading list and information. Help me on How to add an AutoResponses on my website so that each event has an auto-response that comes from me when someone signs up for that event.

Thanks
N

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [MX Notify](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-notify-control)? You can setup all kinds of rules and is really easy to use!